# Javascript factory function returns unmodified property

Tags: javascript, factory

Can someone explain why myForm.getSettings() and myForm.oSettings return a different result here?

```js
var Form = (function() {
  var oSettings = {
    test: 'something'
  };

  function init(oOptions) {
    oSettings = oOptions;
  }

  function getSettings() {
    return oSettings;
  }

  return {
    init: init,
    getSettings: getSettings,
    oSettings: oSettings
  }
});

var myForm = Form();
myForm.init({
  test2: 'Something else'
});

console.log(myForm.getSettings()); // Returns {test2: 'Something else'}
console.log(myForm.oSettings); // Returns {test: 'something'}, expecting {test2: 'Something else'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of object references. Your `Form` function returns an object which has property `oSettings` points to `{ test: 'something' }`. After that, you call `myForm.init()` which reassigns the variable `oSettings` inside your `Form` function to `{ test2: 'Something else' }`. This has nothing to do with the object already returned by calling `Form()`. When you call `myForm.getSettings()`, you get the newly-assigned object. When you call `myForm.oSettings`, you get the original object declared before runtime.

Comment: Minor niggle: "_you get the original object declared at compile time_" - javascript is not a compiled language.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, I corrected it more more precise meaning.

Comment: Is there a way to make the factory pattern expose these properties without a getter function for each? Or should I just use a class?

Comment: There's a way to modify this function so it works like you expect. But the best way is to use a class. It's better for getter setter operations.